# Ruby on rails get # params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I am trying to do something on the backend if i get a #test in the query string but i cant seem to find that.

does any one know how to get those variables?

sample url

```
loocalhost:3000/#test
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't detect it in the backend during the request because this portion is never sent to the server - possible duplicate of [Get request part after hash sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275214/get-request-part-after-hash-sign)

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html).

From http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html

> A reference to a particular part of a document may, including the
>   fragment identifier, look like
>
> http://www.myu.edu/org/admin/people#andy
>
> in which case the string "#andy" is not sent to the server, but is
>   retained by the client and used when the whole object had been
>   retrieved.